# live and pending entries together not working

Tags: templating, entries, status, pending

Craft 3.0.37

I have the following code which I expect to output all entries (live and pending) but it doesn't

```
<ul>
  {% for entry in craft.entries.section('podcast').status('live','pending').relatedTo(season).orderBy('postDate', 'asc').all() %}
    <li ><span>{{ entry.episodeNumber }}</span> <a href="{{ entry.url }}"> {{ entry.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If I change the status to only pending it outputs pending entries, if live, outputs live. However it will not output both pending and live.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `status(['live','pending'])` to get all entries with both states.

Later, to get the linked entry you need to setup a custom route like `podcasts/{slug}. In the template you query the entry like this:

```
{% set slug = craft.request.lastSegment() %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.slug(slug).status(['live', 'pending']).one() %}
```